# RxJava Observable problems

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

Testing on android 6.0.1 Samsung s6 edge+

When device screen is offline and unplugged from debug, the observable simply stop emitting items. If device is turned on, object start being emitted.
Another problem is that randomically before stopping reciving items, i get 2/3 duplicate calls in sequence of the same item

```
Observable.interval(4000,
            30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(ErrorResponse.handleError()).subscribe(new Action1() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Object o) {
                            statusSender.doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult();
                        }
                    });
```

__________________________________EDIT__________________________________

Doing another post to give more details. I cannot give you full log but i'll try to explain better what I've done to be sure that problem is Observable.

following

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/operators/IntervalExampleActivity.java

I tryed a different implementation with Rxjava2

```
isposables.add(statusSender.getObservable(certificate)
                    .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(getObserver()))
```

getObservable method

```
return io.reactivex.Observable.interval(INITIAL_DELAY,Utilities.getInstance().getHeartbeatFrequency(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

getObserver method is asExample with difference that i do my network call inside the onNext

```
private DisposableObserver<Long> getObserver() {
    return new DisposableObserver<Long>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long value) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onNext : value : " + value);
            statusSender.doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onError : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, " onComplete");
        }
    };
}
```

Log of what is happening

[image: Log]

Comment: what's your subscriber do? where do you unsubscribe/subscribe again to this observable? what do you mean 'before stopping receiving items'?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't give all the info. My subscriber send a ping to a remote server to let server know device is alive. I mean "receiving items" on server

Comment: does the Observable not emit items or the server didn't get pings? the same goes for the duplicate calls, does the Observable emit duplicate items or the server received duplicate items?

Comment: It's observable problem. leaving the phone disconnected for a while and taking log after I can see that observer stop being invoked..but when I wake up the  device multiple call are done, as stored in a queue that is being processed

Comment: if that's Observable problem so please provide more details, log, how exactly are you reaching server in the subscribe, where do you unsubscribe from the Observable

Comment: throwing some thoughts: might be that somehow network calls are queued and not actually sent (probably because of that the phone is sleep - doze?), those the network are queued and dispatched at once when the device is wakeup?

Comment: i posted an answer to clarify better what i found

Comment: I'll look, BTW, You should not post additional info as an answer, just edit your question, and add it there

Comment: based on your extended info, you should check what's happen with your network call, you can start but simply add log after the operation (`statusSender.doNetworkCallAndGetStringResult();`), to see the timing, how much time the operation took. another point is , how do you do the network call? you observe on the main thread so do you fork the work to a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

> When device screen is offline and unplugged from debug, the observable simply stop emitting items.

That is expected behavior on Android: the device will pause your activity and switch to a low-power mode to conserve battery. If you need to do something in the background, you will nee to create a Service, request wake-ups via Android-specific timers, and ask for special permission to keep the device on in your manifest (I think, it's been a while).

Comment: the observer is  registered inside a service

Comment: That's not enough - see https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html